# Перевод из Pascal в C#

Tags: c#, pascal

```
var
  n, m, i, j, k, l, min, d, max: integer;
  x, y: array [1..10] of integer;
begin
  assign(input,'input.txt'); reset(input);
  assign(output,'output.txt'); rewrite(output);
  read(n,m); read(k);
  for l:=1 to k do read(x[l],y[l]);
  max:=0;
  for i:=1 to n do for j:=1 to m do begin
    min:=n+m;
    for l:=1 to k do begin
      d:= abs(i-x[l])+abs(j-y[l]);
      if d<min then min:=d
    end;
    if min>max then max:=min
  end;
  write(max);
  close(output)
end.
```

Comment: А вы сами пробовали? Хотя-бы пояснили, что делает ваш код и привели бы примеры входного и выходного файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У языков важные отличия.

- Вы не сможете нативно читать с консоли через пробел, как это может паскаль. Поэтому после ввода каждой группы чисел нужно нажимать **Enter**.
- Нумерация массивов начинается с **0**, а не с **1**.

```csharp
Console.Write("Введите n m k: ");
string[] s = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int n = Convert.ToInt32(s[0]);
int m = Convert.ToInt32(s[1]);
int k = Convert.ToInt32(s[2]);
int[]
    x = new int[k],
    y = new int[k];
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Введите x[{0}] y[{0}]: ", i);
    s = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    x[i] = Convert.ToInt32(s[0]);
    y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(s[1]);
}
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        int min = n + m;
        for (int l = 0; l < k; l++)
        {
            int d = Math.Abs(i - x[l]) + Math.Abs(j - y[l]);
            if (d < min) min = d;
        }
        if (min > max) max = min;
    }
Console.WriteLine("Результат max: {0}", max);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=951
Вот эта задача, я не до конца понял как реализовать на c#. В интернете нашел только код на паскале.

Comment: Простите, забыл добавить ссылку на задачу

Comment: @trueblackfox здесь не решают задачи за вас. Здесь помогают вам с проблемами при решении, которое вы выполняете сами. Я вам перевел код, и то по той простой причине, что я знаю оба языка. Берите код, что я написал, тестируйте, исправляйте. Если вы совершенно ничего не понимаете в C#, [начните учиться](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ). Приложите пожалуйста к этому немного больше усилий, чем приложил я, отвечая на ваш вопрос, который даже не вопрос.

Comment: Я более-менее знаю с#. Просто у меня идет учебная практика, хотелось быстрее все сделать, ибо у меня еще 12 задач. Я тут в стековерфлоу впервые, не знал, что здесь так работает, буду знать)

Answer (score -1):

var a:integer;
begin
writeln ('Сколько вам лет?');
read (a);
if (a>=18) then writeln ('Замечательно. Вы уже можете водить автомобиль') else writeln ('К сожалению, водить автомобиль Вам рановато');
end.